# Highlight cells in a column from active cell down to Variable row

Tags: excel, vba

I would like some help finishing of this piece of code. I need to highlight cells in a column from active cell down to Variable row.

Snippet of my code:

```
Start = Cells.Find(What:="MEETING", After:=ActiveCell, LookIn:=xlFormulas, _
        LookAt:=xlWhole, SearchOrder:=xlByRows, SearchDirection:=xlNext, _
        MatchCase:=False, SearchFormat:=False).Activate
ActiveCell.Offset(7, 0).Select

Range(ActiveCell & Stop).Select 'it is this bit that doesn't work
```

Answer (score 0):

You rarely have to activate or select a range

```
Sub BrokenPiece()

    Dim rStart As Range
    Dim rStop As Range
    Dim CompleteSelection As Range

    Set rStart = Cells.Find(What:="MEETING", After:=ActiveCell, LookIn:=xlFormulas, LookAt:=xlWhole, SearchOrder:=xlByRows, SearchDirection:=xlNext, MatchCase:=False, SearchFormat:=False)

    If Not rStart Is Nothing Then
        Set rStop = rStart.Offset(7, 0)

        Set CompleteSelection = Range(rStart, rStop)

        CompleteSelection.Select

    End If

End Sub
```

If you want to find the address of the last occurrence of Note: in Columns(1).

> DateStop = Columns(1).Find(What:="Note:", LookAt:=xlPart, SearchDirection:=xlPrevious, MatchCase:=False).Row - 2

You would first set your range

> DateStop = Columns(1).Find(What:="Note:", LookAt:=xlPart, SearchDirection:=xlPrevious, MatchCase:=False)

Then make sure that you actually found something

> If not DateStop is nothing then

Now there are to ways to get the row that you want

> result = DateStop.Row -2

or

> result = DateStop.Offset(-2).Row

If you choose the Offset method, you should test that DateStop.Row -2 is a valid row.  In this you will not throw an error

> If DateStop.Row -2 > 0 then

So let's put it together

```
Function DateStopRowMinus2()

    Dim DateStop
    Set DateStop = Columns(1).Find(What:="Note:", LookAt:=xlPart, SearchDirection:=xlPrevious, MatchCase:=False)
    If Not DateStop Is Nothing Then
        If DateStop.Row - 2 > 0 Then

            DateStopRowMinus2 = DateStop.Offset(-2)

        End If
    End If

End Function
```

Notice when I referred to the Offset of DateStop, I didn't specify a column.  That is because the Offset property takes two optional parameters

> Offset([Row], [Column])

We know that they are optional because the parameters are enclosed in square brackets [].  Here are some valid examples

- Range("A10").Offset(2)
- Range("A10").Offset(2, 0)
- Range("A10").Offset(0, 2)
- Range("A10").Offset(0, 2)
- Range("A10").Offset(,2)
- Range("A10").Offset(2, 2)

Comment: Thank you Thomas. how would I derive the 'address' of this..           {DateStop = Columns(1).Find(What:="Note:", LookAt:=xlPart, SearchDirection:=xlPrevious, MatchCase:=False).Row - 2}